# woocommerce automatically adding a word before price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The prices in my woocommerce store have the words **"starting from" automatically added in front of them** and I want to remove these words.

This happens on all products both variable and regular products. I need a code that will allow me to completely remove the words that come before the price.

**screen shots:**

[screen shot - regular product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsUzJ.png)

[screen shot - variable product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5T7D.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove **"starting from"** prefix from displayed prices, try the following code in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_get_price_html_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_get_price_html_callback( $price, $product ) {
    return str_replace( __('starting from'), '', $price );
}
```

Similarly for single product pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_get_price_html_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_get_price_html_callback( $price, $product ) {
    if ( is_product() )
        $price = str_replace( __('starting from'), '', $price );

    return $price;
}
```

**Note: Please replace 'starting from' according to your need.**